# Prove that $\frac{d}{dx} (f(x))^2=2*f(x)f'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

A problem in my textbook (page $280$), http://classicalrealanalysis.info/com/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Portrait.pdf, said:

**Prove that $\frac{d}{dx} (f(x))^2=2*f(x)f'(x)$ using Theorem 7.7 and also directly from the definition of derivative.**

So I proved it.

*Proof*

Note that $\frac{d}{dx} (f(x))^2= \frac{d}{dx} [f(x)f(x)]$

Then $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)f(x)]$ = $f(x)f'(x)+f'(x)f(x)=2f(x)f'(x)$

$\square$

This proof seems too obvious given the way that the question is worded. Theorem 7.7 basically just gives you your algebraic operations under differentation (sum, product, quotient rules, etc.) and the limit definition of derivative doesn't seem necessary here.

My proof is correct, but does it satisfy the question? It seems too easy.

Comment: Your proof is valid, and you could also prove it with the chain rule, but the question asked also for proof directly from the definition of derivative

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Right, so how should I get started on that?

Comment: The question probably (possibly?) implies using the limit definition of a derivative to get the result.

Comment: Yes, start with the definition of derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof directly from the definition of the derivative. We have:

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)^{2} &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)^{2} - f(x)^{2}}{h} \\&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\big(f(x + h) - f(x)\big)\big(f(x + h) + f(x)\big)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\big(f(x+h) + f(x)\big)\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\lim_{h\to 0}\big(f(x + h) + f(x)\big)\\&=2f(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\end{align}$$

Using the definition of a derivative:

$$\boxed{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)^{2} = 2f(x)f'(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

As hint:$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f^2(x+t)-f^2(x)}{t}=\\
\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f^2(x+t)-f(x+t)f(x)+f(x+t)f(x)-f^2(x)}{t}=\\
\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x+t)(f(x+t)-f(x))+f(x)(f(x+t)-f(x))}{t}=\\
\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x+t)(f(x+t)-f(x))}{t}+\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x)(f(x+t)-f(x))}{t}=\\$$can you take over now ?

Comment: How is it the case that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\lim_{h\to 0}\big(f(x + h) + f(x)\big)=2f(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ ?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\big(f(x + h) + f(x)\big) = 2f(x)$ by directly substituting $h = 0$

Comment: i think you may ask from @Joshua Wang , but it is because $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$ and properties of $\lim f(x).g(x)=\lim f(x).\lim g(x)$